# How do Dark Side and Light Side points work with regard to your faction?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I know that gaining points in one primary direction will allow you to unlock special items, but I was wondering how it affected your standing with your chosen faction.  If I'm playing as a Jedi of the Republic, and go down the dark side path, do I become a Sith and/or have the option of joining the Empire?  Do other Jedi or "good guys" respond less favorably towards me?

Comment: Dark/Light and Empire/Republic are totally orthogonal in the game. All combinations are possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot change factions in TOR — what you pick is what you get.

That said, there are small differences depending on whether you are Light Side / Dark Side, such as verbal cosmetic changes in conversation.  And your choices may affect companion affection.

Flashpoints are repeatable and have up to +/- 250 points' worth of dark/light decisions among them, and Diplomacy crew missions can yield DSP/LSP as well, so you can always completely reverse your stance (although that could potentially take a /lot/ of work...).

Comment: So it doesn't change how others interact with you?

Comment: @MatthewRead I believe it does, actually, but its just a verbal cosmetic change. You get the same results from the conversation. It also affects Companion affection, if you go against their tendencies.