# What are the advantages/disadvantages of having a light/dark side alignment of the opposing side?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Dark Side and Light Side points work with regard to your faction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42227/how-do-dark-side-and-light-side-points-work-with-regard-to-your-faction)

In Star Wars the Old Republic, you can earn alignment points towards light side or dark side from conversation choices and other actions.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of having a high alignment in the opposing side of the force?

Comment: @LessPop That question is more focused on what advantages/disadvantages there are for going Light/Dark at all. It doesn't specifically ask for nor do any of the answers address whether or not going specifically Light Sith or Dark Jedi have alternate consequences.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I agree with LessPop. Not a duplicate, but it is a good idea to have it referenced because they have similar and slightly overlapping Answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far the only thing I have found that has your alignment as a requirement are the light and dark side items which are sold for Republic, in the Republic fleet. There are two shops at either end of the shopping concourse which sell light and dark items.

All of which have an alignment requirement.

Your alignment also affects your companions, just as with Kotor. For example, I play Jedi Guardian with T7 as my companion and he values honour and justice. So usually when I make a light side choice, my affinity with him goes up.

I would imagine this is the same for the other classes and sides.

Comment: I'm going to say that it doesn't affect your companions... the awnser does not the light or dark side points... As a Sith assassin using Khem Vhal (Which btw is a serious evil dude, taking the dark side won't always give me +rep with him, but sometimes even -rep. Because he value's the strong and praying on the weak isn't it... even tho it's the only dark choice)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the "opposing side" part of the question, but one general benefit of high dark side alignment is

**Sith Corruption**

Dark Side users do get a little visual change as they get darker. It's called Sith Corruption and can be turned off in the options if you don't like it.

The following images show the effect. It's subtle, but cool.

[image: Sith Corruption 1] [image: Sith Corruption 2]

... and so on for each dark side level.

Or see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQrFvuThLII) or [Sith Corruption comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwhKM.png) image.

(This is similar to the shrinking or deepening scars Shepard had as he grew more Paragon or Renegade in Mass Effect 2, also made by Bioware.)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest effect I've seen is that of convenience... Most people in the Empire tend towards 'dark' and in Republic towards 'light' (at least in the first months). That means you're more likely to find items that have the opposite restriction (and cheaper) in the AH since they drop at the same rate, yet less people want them.

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen so far, choosing either Light or Dark has mostly cosmetic effects.

Even your companion is easy to be persuaded: one gift is enough to compensate a 'wrong' decision.

So my advice is to do whatever you feel is 'right' for your character.

Might it turn out to be wrong, it's possible to go to the other extreme by playing some Flash Points over and over. So the choise you make now is not forever.